# Reading .csv file in php

Tags: php, csv

I want to read .csv file in PHP and put its contents into the database. I wrote the following code:

```
$row = 1;
$file = fopen("qryWebsite.csv", "r");
while (($data = fgetcsv($file, 8000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    $row++;
    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
        echo $data[$c] . "\n";}}
fclose($file);
```

I do not get any error but it does not show me result.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I am using [parseCSV](https://code.google.com/p/parsecsv-for-php/) class to read data from csv files. It can give more flexibility in reading csv file.

Answer (score 7):

this is not tested... but something like this should do the trick:

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("xxxxxxxxx.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";   
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            $blackpowder = $data;
            $dynamit = implode(";", $blackpowder);
            $pieces = explode(";", $dynamit);
            $col1 = $pieces[0];
            $col2 = $pieces[1];
            $col3 = $pieces[2];
            $col4 = $pieces[3];
            $col5 = $pieces[5];
            mysql_query("
                INSERT INTO `xxxxxx` 
                    (`xxx`,`xxx`,`xxx`,`xxxx`,`xxx`) 
                VALUES 
                    ('".$col1."','".$col2."','".$col3."','".$col4."','".$col5."')
            ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pointless. Why not use `LOAD DATA` that can handle CSV utilising `TERMINATED BY`

Comment: @Gary, `LOAD DATA` is often disabled on shared hosting due to the possible security threat.

Comment: @Gary & Charles and i took on his attempt

Comment: Any good hosting company should have access to phpMyAdmin which can import CSV. If not, copy it to your host and use it. Even phpMiniAdmin can import CSV.

Comment: Maybe he's designing something for clients of a website to be able to import data.

Answer (score 6):

```
$fp = fopen('ReadMe.csv','r') or die("can't open file");
print "<table>\n";
while($csv_line = fgetcsv($fp,1024)) {
    print '<tr>';
    for ($i = 0, $j = count($csv_line); $i < $j; $i++) {
        print '<td>'.$csv_line[$i].'</td>';
    }
    print "</tr>\n";
}
print '</table>';
fclose($fp) or die("can't close file");
```

[More Details](http://webexplorar.com/read-csv-file-using-php/)

Answer (score 3):

One liner to parse a CSV file into an array by using **[str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php#114764)**.

```
$csv = array_map( 'str_getcsv', file( 'qryWebsite.csv' ) );
```

To build a database query that will import all the values into database at once:

```
$query = 
    "INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES " .
    implode( ',', array_map( function( $params ) use ( &$values ) {
        $values = array_merge( (array) $values, $params );
        return '(' . implode( ',', array_fill( 0, count( $params ), '?' ) ) . ')';
    }, $csv ) );
```

This will build a prepared statement with question mark placeholders, like:

```sql
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES (?,?,?),(?,?,?),(?,?,?),(?,?,?)
```

, and variable `$values` will be one-dimensional array that holds values for the statement. One caveat here is that csv file should contain less than 65,536 entries ( maximum number of placeholders ).

Answer (score 2):

Try this....

In PHP it is often useful to be able to read a CSV file and access it’s data. That is where the fgetcsv() function comes in handy, it will read each line of a CSV file and assign each value into an ARRAY. You can define the separator in the function as well see PHP docs for [fgetcsv()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) for more options and examples.

```
function readCSV($csvFile){
    $file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
    while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
        $line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    }
    fclose($file_handle);
    return $line_of_text;
}


// Set path to CSV file
$csvFile = 'test.csv';

$csv = readCSV($csvFile);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($csv);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the [composer package manager](http://getcomposer.org/), you can also rely on `league/csv`

According to theire [documentation](https://csv.thephpleague.com/9.0/):

```php
use League\Csv\Reader;

//load the CSV document from a file path
$csv = Reader::createFromPath('/path/to/your/csv/file.csv', 'r');
$csv->setHeaderOffset(0);

$header = $csv->getHeader(); //returns the CSV header record
$records = $csv->getRecords(); //returns all the CSV records as an Iterator object
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code. It works perfect for me. I have comment to make it more understandable. You can take reference from this code.

```
<?php

//display error message if any
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

//openup connection to database
include('dbconnection.php');

//open csv file
if (($handle = fopen("files/cities.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {

    $flag = true;
    $id=1;

    //fetch data from each row
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        if ($flag) {
            $flag = false;
            continue;
        }

        //get data from each column
        $city_id      = $data[0];
        $country_name = $data[1];
        $city_name    = $data[2];
        $state_code   = $data[3];

        //query to insert to database
        $sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO `DB_Name`.`cities` 
                (`id`,`city_id`, country_name`, `city_name`,`state_code`)
                VALUES 
                ('$id','$city_id','$country_name','$city_name','$state_code')";

        echo $sql;

        //execute the insertion query
        $retval = mysql_query($sql, $conn);

        if($retval == false )
        {
          die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        echo "<p style='color: green;'>Entered data having id = " .$id. " successfully</p><br>";
        $id++;
    }

    echo "<br><p style='color: orange;'>Congratulation all data successfully inserted</p>";

    fclose($handle);
}

//close the connection
mysql_close($conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
$cel_values = [];`
$column_keys = [];
if (($handle = fopen("imagenes_1.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $values = [];
        $num = count($data);
        $row++;
        for ($c = 0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            if($row == 1){
                $column_keys[] = $data[$c]; 
            }else{
                $values[] = $data[$c];
            }
        }
        if($row != 1){
            $cel_values[] = (object) array_combine($column_keys, $values);
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

var_dump($cel_values);
exit;
```

Result

```
array(20) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(10) "0000000000"
    ["date"]=>
    string(26) "2023-02-24 15:46:44.000000"
    ["name"]=>
    string(26) "1-16772509601764653725.png"
  }
  ...
}
```