# Import csv into database only take one row

Tags: php, csv

i have this code but it only take the first row of my csv file ..I already search the internet but none make me understand since i am very new in php ..i m sorry if this question is a duplicate.

```
if(isset($_POST["Import"])){
echo $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
{
    $file = fopen($filename, "r");
    while (($getData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
    {

        $sql = "INSERT INTO book (book_id,total_book,price,title,author,surname,genre,location) values 
        ('$getData[0]','$getData[1]','$getData[2]','$getData[3]','$getData[4]','$getData[5]','$getData[6]','$getData[7]')";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        var_dump($sql);die;
        // var_dump(mysqli_error_list($con));
        // exit();
        if(!isset($result))
        {
            echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                        alert(\"Invalid File:Please Upload CSV File.\");
                        window.location = \"bookList.php\"
                      </script>";
        }
        else {
            echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                    alert(\"CSV File has been successfully Imported.\");
                    window.location = \"bookList.php\"
                </script>";
        }
    }

    fclose($file);
}
```

}

Comment: You have added `var_dump($sql);die;` & added the script tags in in the while loop . Remove those. In while loop, each row is traversed. Let the while loop complete, it will save all records

Comment: var_dump($sql);die; because you added die, code is exit after running once.

Comment: even i remove that ,its still take only the first row

Comment: look here, maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455872/reading-csv-file-in-php

Comment: while(! feof($file))
  {
  print_r(fgetcsv($file));
  } try this are you getting all data

Answer (score 0):

You can try in my way i did this to process user attendance save in database.
here my code below i am giving upload to data save in server/db.

```
//after form post with file 
    if (isset($_POST["frmUplaod"])) {
    extract($_POST);
    $filename = basename($_FILES['attendance_file']['name']);
    $targetfolder = 'Attendance/'. $filename .'';
      if ($filename != "") {

         move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attendance_file']['tmp_name'], $targetfolder);
         chmod($targetfolder, 0777);
         $msg = "Attendance file succesfully updated";
      }
    }
```

after that i process this csv file using this code :

```
function MakeID($id) {

            $refine_id = "";
            if (strlen($id) == "1") {
                $refine_id = "SUL00" . $id;
            } elseif (strlen($id) == "2") {
                $refine_id = "SUL0" . $id;
            } elseif (strlen($id) == "3") {
                $refine_id = "SUL" . $id;
            } else {
                $refine_id = "SUL".$id;
            }

            return $refine_id;
        }
//336668677
//Read directory
        $FileArray = scandir("Attendance");

        $i = 0;
        $existsdate = array();



        foreach ($FileArray as $f) {

            $filename = "Attendance/" . $f;

            $extensiondebug='';
            if(!empty($f))
            {
                $splitex=explode(".",$f);
                $extensiondebug=$splitex[1];
            }

            if ($extensiondebug == "csv") {


                $row = 1;

                if (($handle = fopen("Attendance/".$f, "r")) !== FALSE) {

                  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

                    $num = count($data);

                    $row++;
                    $terminal_id=1;
                    $emp_code=MakeID($data['1']);



                    $pd=split('/',$data[0]);
                    @$raw_date=$pd[2]."-".$pd[1]."-".$pd[0];
                    $unixtime=strtotime($raw_date);
                    $date=date('Y-m-d',$unixtime);
                    //echo $date."<br>";
                    if($data['1']!="ID" && $date!="1970-01-01")
                    {

                        if($data['6']!="00:00" && $data['6']!="0:00")
                        {


                            //echo $data['6']."<br>";


                            //echo $date;



                            $time=date('g:i:s',strtotime($data['6']));

                            //exit();


                            $res = $con->existsByCondition("attendance_raw", " employee_id='$emp_code' AND date='$date' AND time='$time'");
                            if ($res <= 0) {
                                $array = array(
                                    "machine_id" => $terminal_id,
                                    "date" => $date,
                                    "time" => $time,
                                    "employee_id" => $emp_code,
                                    "result" => "1"
                                    );
                                $con->insert("attendance_raw", $array);
                            }
                        }

                        if($data['7']!="00:00" && $data['7']!="0:00")
                        {
                            $time2=date('g:i:s',strtotime($data['7']));
                            $res = $con->existsByCondition("attendance_raw", " employee_id='$emp_code' AND date='$date' AND time='$time2'");
                            if ($res <= 0) {
                                $array = array(
                                    "machine_id" => $terminal_id,
                                    "date" => $date,
                                    "time" => $time2,
                                    "employee_id" => $emp_code,
                                    "result" => "1"
                                    );
                                $con->insert("attendance_raw", $array);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    //echo "<br />\n";

                }

                fclose($handle);

            }

                    rename($filename, 'read/' . $filename);
                    echo "file moved to specified directory.";
                }

            }
```

I hope this will help you to complete your csv file process.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the help ..I already solve the problem ,the problem in my code is only the delimiter that i used ,i used a wrong delimiter